# NSMutableArray addObjects NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an problem with NSString and NSMutableArray

I Have:

`NSString *msgID;
NSMutableArray *mArray;`

and `msgID` string is an unique ID for every message and it changes it self every time when you receive a new message.
and now i want to save those IDS into NSMutableArray to put them inside plist file.

but the problem is when i do like the following

```
a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[a addObject:msgID];
```

it save only the first ID not the rest of theme

Example if the output ID is `65465465151` and you received new message after one second with ID `2123545445` the NSMutableArray save only the first output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>65465465151</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

how can I make `NSMutableArray` add all outputs or strings which already output using one `NSString`  ?

Here is my code

```
NSString *msgID = [viewcontroller.messageID substringFromIndex:[viewcontroller.messageID length] - 21];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"msgIDs.plist"]; 
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableArray *mArray;

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])  {
       path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"msgIDs.plist"] ];
} 
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])  {
      mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      [mArray addObject:msgID];
} else {
    // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
    mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[mArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Seems like you are creating your plist before you add your second object in to the array. Check there.

Comment: Or maybe you are allocating new array each time. I've seen similar mistakes before.

Comment: can you check my edit ?

Comment: Kinda looks like you're recreating the array for every message you receive.

Comment: Also there is some strange logic error with your paths that I can't figure out. Do you realise that you only write to `plist.plist`? What is `msgIDs.plist` for? Your if statements are very confusing as well.

Comment: fixed correction error :D

Comment: Ok with a single plist your `if statements` just got more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your code, and it's all in one block like that and not spread over several methods, in several different loops, then you're creating a new instance of `mArray` every time you go through the code block, and, as a result, at most there will be one entry in the array.

Comment: Well, I can't make much sense of your code, but you need to move the array declaration and creation to a point "more global" than that code block.  (If you don't understand this then you probably should not be writing Objective-C -- it's not a very forgiving language.)

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks OK, provided you are not trying to create the array in a loop repeatedly. Each `addObject` will enlarge the array by one. Make sure you write your plist file after the array is populated the way you expect. Make sure any old plist file is overwritten.

Comment: How is it implied that the array is created in a loop?